# Finding index of more than one object

Tags: java, collections

I create this code just for my own understanding. I have a person class and a List to store all my Person objects. I added the same object twice to illustrate my question. How do I find the index of those objects?

How do I find the indexes of the two Andy Bernards?

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName,String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return String.format(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);  
    }
}



List<Person> deletePeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person createPerson = new Person("Andy","Bernard"); 
Person createTwo = new Person("Micheal","Scott");
deletePeople.add(createPerson);           
deletePeople.add(createTwo);         
deletePeople.add(createPerson);
/* for (Person display : deletePeople) {
    if(display.getFirstName().equals("Andy")) {
        System.out.println(deletePeople.indexOf(display));
    }
} */ 
}
```

Comment: I think you would have a much easier time using a `Map` than trying to find people by list indexes

Comment: @Rogue - I know what you mean. Map is a key,  object pair. But let's say two people have the same name, can I get the index of both?

Comment: You could try assigning unique identifiers to the users, and index based on that

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, add .equals() and .hashCode() methods to class Person so you can identify a Person object as being the same.

Second, use indexOf() and lastIndexOf() methods in class List to find the first and last Andy Bernard objects.

Comment: What if there are 3 Andy Bernards? Must you iterate over the list yourself?

Comment: All `indexOf` does is iterate over the list.

Comment: @DavidConrad indexOf "returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element."  (From the API)

Comment: And how do you suppose it finds the specified element? Quoting from the javadoc of `java.util.AbstractList#indexOf`: "This implementation first gets a list iterator (with `listIterator()`). Then, it iterates over the list until the specified element is found or the end of the list is reached."

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is a list of indexes into the list where objects match your criteria, and there can be more than one, then you will need to iterate the list yourself, and save the indexes to some sort of list.

If what you want is simply to delete the matching items, then you can use java.util.Iterator (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to iterate over the collection, and invoke the Iterator's `remove()` method on each matching object as you encounter it.

Comment: Just want to display the index, not delete. How would I go about  iterating the list myself, and save the indexes to some sort of list.

Comment: You already have the code to iterate (the part that's commented out).

Comment: Ah - i see your problem. Use the "long version" of the for loop. E.g. `for(int i=0; i < deletePeople.size(); i++) { Person p = deletePeople.get(i);}`